# Good resources for learning the http protocol in depth

Tags: http, https

I work with the web and would like to get a more in depth knowledge of the http protocol.  For my learning style I kind of learn best by having a book to read, all resources are welcome though.  I saw Htttp: The Definitive Guide, but that was published in 2002 and seems like it might be a bit dated by now(though I could be wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try reading the specications? (see http://httpwg.github.io/specs/)

Comment: Just glanced over it, at the very least, that will be a great place to start.  Maybe the only thing I need.

Answer (score 0):

you should read  [RFC2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) as a base document firstly. Also about depth knowledge of the http protocol you should read other RFCs which are related with RFC2616(for example: [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) HTTP Basic and Digest Authentication and others). I think reading RFC documents more useful to get depth knowledge because sometimes other books miss out some topics.

Comment: RFC 2616 is obsolete.